# How to google form with multiple sections, each section with a dropdown list, populate from Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form with multiple sections, each section with a dropdown list. I wish to pull the data for the dropdown lists from spreadsheet with matching name.

[Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1cuPfuzzoEPEaIliiRKDqUvZ3dq4vawDPLERZYMUwpZQ/edit)

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQk2CoBIu37Vy7hbg7ZYvvEwzj-x8SCR5MSGrZ1ngAs/edit#gid=285833079)

Execution log
4:42:11 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:42:18 PM  Error
Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:23
populateGoogleForms @ Code.gs:17

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(`your text`);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormList");
  const [hA, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const cols = {};
  const col={};
  const idx={};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]).filter(e=>e);col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });
  return cols;
}

function populateGoogleForms() {
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = `1cuPfuzzoEPEaIliiRKDqU`your text`vZ3dq4vawDPLERZYMUwpZQ`;
  const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
  const items = googleForm.getItems();
  const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
    if (itemTitle in choices) {
      const itemType = item.getType();
      switch (itemType) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
          break;
        default:
          Logger.log("Ignore question", itemTitle);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values.` might be due to the values of `const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();`. When the values of each array have duplicated values, such an error occurs at `setChoiceValues`. In order to remove this, when your script is modified, as a simple modification, how about the following modification? Please modify your `getDataFromGoogleSheets()` as follows.

#### From:

```
hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = rows.map(r => r[i]).filter(e=>e);col[h]=i+1;idx[h]=i; });
```

#### To:

```
hA.forEach((h, i) => { cols[h] = [...new Set(rows.map(r => r[i]).filter(e => e))]; col[h] = i + 1; idx[h] = i; });
```

- In this modification, the duplicated values are removed with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
- As another modification, how about modifying `getDataFromGoogleSheets()` as follows?

  ```js
  function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FormList");
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    const cols = Object.fromEntries(values[0].map((_, col) => {
      const [h, ...v] = values.flatMap(row => row[col] || []);
      return [h, [...new Set(v)]];
    }));
    return cols;
  }
  ```
- By the way, in your script, at `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(`your text`);`, an argument is used like `your text`. In this case, `getActiveSpreadsheet` has no arguments. Please be careful about this.

Comment: i have Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQk2CoBIu37Vy7hbg7ZYvvEwzj-x8SCR5MSGrZ1ngAs/edit#gid=285833079

Comment: Execution log
9:38:04 PM Notice Execution started
9:38:07 PM Error 
Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:22
populateGoogleForms @ Code.gs:16

Comment: @VanoTate Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your provided Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again? By the way, when I tested this modification using a sample Spreadsheet, no error occurrs. I apologize for this situation.